# WordPress Sorting by characts - Swedish characters

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My website is in Swedish and i will write about different kind of topics.
In sweden we have these kind of characters too ö, ä & å. 
I have created a page where i will show only CPT posts that start with character A.
The problem that i am now getting is that

When showing posts that start with Ä then it also shows posts starting with A & Å.
Same thing if i for example want to show posts starting with O then it shows posts starting with Ö also.

How do i go about to filter out right.

**Here is my code**

```
    <?php
//get all post IDs for posts start with letter A, in title order,
//display posts
global $wpdb;
$char_a = 'A';


$postids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT      ID
FROM        $wpdb->posts
WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) = %s
ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title",$char_a)); 

if ($postids) {
$args=array(
  'post__in' => $postids,
  'post_type' => 'encyklopedi',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  // 'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
 // echo 'List of Posts Titles beginning with the letter '. $char_a;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent 

Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php endwhile; } else { ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Kunde inte hitta några inlägg som börjar med A...' ); ?></p>
<?php }
wp_reset_query(); } ?>
```

Is it maybe only something that i should do in $char_a = '***Here***'; or maybe something in functions too ?

Comment: You could try converting your database's character set from UTF-8 (typical default in mySQL) to swe7(The Swedish character set.)  Never messed with character sets specifically for WordPress, so... this might break things horribly so make sure your backup is good.

Comment: CORRECTION: use utf8_swedish_ci.  I believe swe7 may be obsolete.